# How can I teach an English speaking person to say my name correctly (Kjetil)

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

I have a purely Norwegian name, Kjetil. It is old norse and means "kettle" or "helmet". A couple of times now, aquaintances and new friends have asked me in chat or person how my name is really pronounced properly. Now, one of them found a youtube video for that:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9hCBk62lX4I

However, sometimes I don't have access to the video. I have yet to find a single word in the English language that makes use of the first sound in my name, K+J. I have tried to find the correct name of the phonetic sound, but it doesn't seem to appear in charts: http://ipa.typeit.org/full/.

CH seems to be the closest I've found. SH is also close, but far too much forward on the tongue. Plus I don't really want to be called Shit-EL, which has happened a lot of times. It sounds like superman's bratty little brother.

So, what is the first sound of my name called, and are there any words in the English language that uses it?

PS: you can call me Cookie if you want.

Edit: This is actually a very important sound in the Norwegian language. It is widely used in everyday words. If you do it wrong, and pronounce it SH, you actually might end up saying rinsing (in water) when you meant chicken.

Comment: I have a Norwegian friend with a very similar problem.  The 'Kj' sound is not natural to English ears.  I've heard him addressed a 'Cudgel -berg'.  He usually accepts 'Sh', which is reasonably easy to explain.

Comment: I watched your video and it sounds like "shyetil" or "chyetil" to me, so that first sound is something like /ʃj/ or /tʃj/.

Comment: I know most english speaking people think it sounds like that, and I can't really blame them, as they are very similar sounds. They are not the same though. KJ is pronounced more at the back of the tongue, compared to SH or CH, where the latter is written phonetically in a similar way as TSH

Comment: It's a [voiceless palatal fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_palatal_fricative), which is apparently the same as the *ch* sound in German *nicht*, and there is no way you will be able to teach English speakers to say it without a lot of effort.

Comment: The exact sound does not exist in English. There's no easy way to explain it. The transcription given on Wikipedia, /ç~ɕ/, to me suggests the sound at the start of "human," but I have no idea if this is actually a good match or not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the pronunciation of a foreign word / name / phoneme, not *English*.

Comment: My French wife gave up long ago trying to expect Virginians to pronounce correctly something as simple as “Laure” (she’s gone with “Laura” for 37 years now), so good luck with your name (here in central Va., at least). That said, it sounds to me kind of like “Chez” (if you can get them to pronounce **that** correctly), so maybe you could tell them it’s like “Chez [L]atte” (without the “L”).

Comment: I listened to that video several times, and that sounds like Cher-Til to me. Like the singer Cher. Or Share-Til. Sh is probably as close as you're likely to get in a casual conversation. What's the scope of the explanation you're looking to give? Can you take 15 minutes to explain this, or just real quick when someone asks?

Comment: Is there a simplified pronunciation that you could live with?

Comment: I like the "Human" variant. It is actually much like human, only with a bit more closed mouth, creating the unvocalized whistle-sound. I think we can conclude with the fact that there are no English words using that Kj sound though...

Comment: ...like Stewie saying Cool Whip!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that it might be off topic. But I wouldn't ask the question if it wasn't for the fact that I have trouble explaniing it to english speakers, so in my mind, the question is as closely related to english as norwegian. I hope there is room for asking questions about English relation to other languages

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the Russian "Shch" or "Щ". The most common way I've heard it explained is that the sound is halfway between 'Sh' and 'Ch'. If you stop moving your mouth, halfway between the words "Fresh" and "Cheese," you will be pronouncing the Norwegian 'Kj-,' or something very very close.

If you feel like teaching them to properly pronounce it, for real, tell them to make the 'Ch' sound, as in "CHeese," then bring their tongue back in their mouth, until the air stream is hitting the back of their bottom teeth. This should be the sound that your name starts with.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, I sit next to a russian woman at work. Unfortunately that sound is not correct. In my opinion, both Sh and Ch uses an active tip of the tongue. The Norwegian Kj- has a completely passive tip of the tongue, and uses the center of the tongue to make the sound. I would say that you need to say Ch- and then roll the tip of the tongue down to the bottom of your mouth.

Comment: Looking online, the Щ sound used to be pronounced 'shch' and still is in some dialects of Russian, but in other dialects it is now pronounced with a consonant quite similar to the Norwegian "kj".